# Command line SIP dialer

Tags: unix, command-line-interface, voip, sip, dial

Is there a simple command line SIP dialer for unix which can connect to SIP server, make a call and play some media file (wav/mp3)? In ideal I would look like this:

```
sip-dailer +1xxxxxxxxxx /path/to/message.mp3
```

Comment: I've done some research into SIP. My sense is that it's very vendor specific. You might have to purchase a specific unix compatible SIP server.

Comment: twilio has an API call for this.  Maybe not one line, but close to.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With sipcmd https://github.com/tmakkonen/sipcmd you can do it on one line:

```
sipcmd -u <login> -c <passwd> -P sip -w <sipproxy> -x "c<phonenum>;ws3000;v<audiofile>;h"
```

Comment: Add your country code in front of the number. Like 001 for the US and Canada.

Answer (score 11):

There is a free (GPL) tool called [SIPp](http://sipp.sourceforge.net/) (distributed as [sip-tester](http://packages.debian.org/testing/comm/sip-tester) by Debian and its derivatives) that will allow you do something along these lines.

For example:

```
./sipp -sn uac <IP address>
```

tells it to use the built in UAC scenario and to send the request to the IP address specified.

Once the call is answered it can play audio, but this needs to be provided as a raw RTP stream (passing a .pcap capture file works well) and you will need to build your own 'scenario' for this, which involves writing/modifying a bit of XML.

Comment: This comment was super useful for me. I wrote up a detailed set of instructions on getting SIPp up and running [here](http://www.sipfish.com/blog/generating-voip-traffic-with-sipp/). Thanks!

Comment: Hello, do you have details on these instructions?

Answer (score 5):

If you already have Asterisk running, setting up a task to dial a number and wait for the other side to answer and play an audio file is not that hard. But 'having Asterisk running' does not answer 'simple'.

Google suggests [pjsua](http://www.pjsip.org/pjsua.htm).

Answer (score 3):

[linphonec](http://www.linphone.org/) support [remote_ring](http://www.linphone.org/eng/documentation/dev/tuning-linphone.html) option(wav file to play to advertise remote ringing). You can configure Asterisk.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it and it was quiet simple, there is a special command `play` for playing WAVs, and config where you can set sip_proxy. Almost what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe have a look at http://www.pjsip.org/pjsua.htm. While I am not sure it has an autoplay-option for outgoing calls, I guess you could fiddle with input devices a little bit to make it possible.

Comment: I've seen this, very interesting library but it's not ready-to-use solution, though there are good python examples howto use it

Answer (score 0):

There is a little simple batch script, using netcat here:

https://github.com/rundekugel/callSip.sh

I use it to test connections and phones. It calls and hang up, but contains no audio support.

Comment: The OP is asking specifically for a solution that can play audio.